# keycloak valid redirect URIs

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am using keycloak 21.0.0 . After changing password, the user is taken to the account console. I am able to change this behaviour,and take the user to a new page, by adding a valid redirect url to the client of "account-console". I have two questions,

1. why is the user taken to account console after the change of password and not to any other page? is the client "account-console" being used in the change password action ? How to identify which client is being used ?
2. Among the many valid redirect uri, how to know which valid-redirect-uri will the user be taken to after change of password ? For example, in the client "account-console", after changing password even though, two valid-redirect-Uris ase present, the user is always taken to "/admin/myrealm/console/" as can be seen in the below snip

[image]